# How to add new fields to existing json

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have output json like this

```
[

"city": [
    {
      "street": "street"
      "zip": "223344"
    }
  ]
    "document": [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "12345678",
      "file_name": "test.xml"
    }
  ]
]
```

and I want to add to "document" new fields so new output will be like this

```
[

"city": [
    {
      "street": "street"
      "zip": "223344"
    }
  ]
    "document": [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "12345678",
      "file_name": "test.xml"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "123456789",
      "file_name": "test2.xml"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "1234567800",
      "file_name": "test3.xml"
    }
  ]
]
```

how can I  add new fields?
I tried do that with a help of  code behind but unfortunately I didn't get correct result

```
payload map(value) -> value ++
document: vars.documentsInfo map {
    date: $.createdAt,
    id: $.id,
    file_name: $.name
  }
```

Comment: Which version of dataweave are you using?

Comment: your JSON is not valid. Also, we don't know what vars.documentsInfo is.

Comment: vars.documentsInfo it's array and I have values for fields which I pointed earlier, json it's only example I described structure where  I want  to add this info

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dw 2.0 and mule runtime 4.2.2 (or later) you can use the **update** function.

**Input**

```
[
  {
    "city": [
      {
        "street": "street",
        "zip": "223344"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "document": [
      {
        "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
        "id": "12345678",
        "file_name": "test.xml"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

**Dataweave Script**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Values
output application/json
var data = [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "123456789",
      "file_name": "test2.xml"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "1234567800",
      "file_name": "test3.xml"
    }
]
---
payload update "document" with flatten(payload.document + data)
```

---

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "city": [
      {
        "street": "street",
        "zip": "223344"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "document": [
      {
        "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
        "id": "12345678",
        "file_name": "test.xml"
      },
      {
        "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
        "id": "123456789",
        "file_name": "test2.xml"
      },
      {
        "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
        "id": "1234567800",
        "file_name": "test3.xml"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Input payload:

```
{
  "city": [
    {
      "street": "street",
      "zip": "223344"
    }
  ],
  "document": [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "12345678",
      "file_name": "test.xml"
    }
  ]
}
```

A flowvar named "documentsInfo":

```
[
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "123456789",
      "file_name": "test2.xml"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "1234567800",
      "file_name": "test3.xml"
    }
]
```

The dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    city: payload.city,
    documents: payload.document ++ vars.documentsInfo
}
```

Produces the output:

```
{
  "city": [
    {
      "street": "street",
      "zip": "223344"
    }
  ],
  "documents": [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "12345678",
      "file_name": "test.xml"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "123456789",
      "file_name": "test2.xml"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "1234567800",
      "file_name": "test3.xml"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately with dataweave, there's currently no good way to 'update' an array, field, or object. So the workaround is to save the initial value, combine it with the new objects that you want to add to the documents array, remove the initial information and add back the combined values. I did so here using `do` in dw2.0, hope it helps:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var obj = {
  "city": [
    {
      "street": "street",
      "zip": "223344"
    }
  ],
  "document": [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "12345678",
      "file_name": "test.xml"
    }
  ]
}

var documents = [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "123456789",
      "file_name": "test2.xml"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-10T04:04:01-08:00",
      "id": "1234567800",
      "file_name": "test3.xml"
    }
]


---
do {
    var originalDoc = obj.document
    var newDocumentsArray = documents ++ originalDoc
    ---
    (obj - "document") ++ {documents: newDocumentsArray}
}
```